# Declaring types for properties generated by a TypeScript class decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, decorator

Let's say I've declared the following class to use as a decorator in TypeScript:

```
class Property {
  static register(...props: Property[]) {
    return function(cls: any) {
      props.forEach(prop => {
        Object.defineProperty(cls.prototype, prop.propertyName, {
          get() {
            return this[`${prop.propertyName}_`] + ' (auto-generated)';
          },
          set(value: any) {
            this[`${prop.propertyName}_`] = value;
          },
        });
      });
    };
  }

  constructor(private readonly propertyName: string) {}
}
```

When applied to a class like this:

```
@Property.register(new Property('myCustomProperty'))
class MyClass {}
```

The result is a class with an auto-generated property setter/getter named `myCustomProperty`:

```
const obj = new MyClass();
obj['myCustomProperty'] = 'asdf';
console.info(obj['myCustomProperty_']); // outputs 'asdf'
console.info(obj['myCustomProperty']); // outputs 'asdf (auto-generated)'
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript does not seem to have any knowledge about this property at compile time since it is being generated at runtime.

What is the best way to ensure TypeScript recognizes the existence of these auto-generated properties? Ideally everything would be auto generated for me so that I didn't have to maintain any extra types somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, I was only accessing the underscored one for demonstration purposes. I only intend to access the non-underscored one, and I was wondering if it was possible to generate a type for that. Or maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, the underscored properties are just an implementation detail for illustration. They aren't really relevant to the question. But you've pretty much answered my question. I'm thinking there may be a way that I can tweak things and make use of mixins instead... but I haven't really considered this as an option yet. Might look into it.

Comment: Why did you make `Property` a class? `register` could easily have been a simple function taking strings as arguments.

Comment: @Bergi Here is the code: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/ShapeShifter/blob/master/src/app/model/properties/Property.ts

Comment: @AlexLockwood OK, it might make sense to pass objects as arguments as you have multiple properties, but none of these "methods" currently can be justified to be an instance method. They don't use `this`, they're essentially static. They would make sense if they didn't take `propertyName` as an argument but rather used the instance property. Also I think it would simplify the code a bit if you had an instance method `createPropertyDescriptor` that returns an object with the respective `set` and `get` functions, instead of calling into `model` methods from the getters/setters.

Comment: I am sure you are probably right given your experience, but do you mind giving a short example? Sorry, I'm a bit new to this language. Here's an example of how I am currently using the class: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/ShapeShifter/blob/master/src/app/model/layers/GroupLayer.ts (basically as a way to easily auto-generate properties on a model class).

Comment: @Bergi Also, the reason why they are instance methods is because the property subclasses override those methods.

Comment: @Bergi did I misunderstand your tip about the instance methods?

Comment: OK, if they're overwritable it makes sense to have them as methods, but still `propertyName` doesn't need to be a parameter.